# Aptana Studio 3 is not creating the projects in the correct directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana

When I create a new Rails project I select the "Use standard 'rails' generator" it creates a new terminal editor with the name of the project and it executes the `rails new .` command but the current location is the path where the Aptana Studio 3 executable was run (I'm using Windows), so all the projects try to be built on the same directory.

Comment: Also when I start a terminal using `Commands > Shell Script > Open Terminal` the terminal doesn't open in the project directory.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I am using Cygwin as my terminal within Aptana.  What kind of terminal was Aptana using when you were using it?